# what is the chance of a deck of cards not having adjacent suits or numbers?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

For example, if we have an Ace of spades, the next card cannot be an Ace nor spades.

Edit: Assuming that we pick one particular shuffle amongst all possible ones

Comment: Assuming a randomly picked shuffle from all possible shuffles? Very interesting (and on first sight tough) problem.

Comment: @orlp yes, sorry for not clarifying!

Comment: @J. Dionisio: What is the source of the problem?

Comment: @quasi my cousin, 12th grade, challenged me to solve it. I believe he came up with it. Combinatorics is my Achille's heel but still, it seems challenging

Comment: @J. Dionisio: Can you find out where your cousin got the problem from?

Comment: @quasi I asked him, he made up the problem. Might I ask why do you want to know?

Comment: To have an idea of whether this was a programming contest problem (*implying brute force would likely be the only real solution*), a math contest problem (*implying there may be some chance at a nice but difficult closed form*), a textbook problem (*implying an easy closed form*), or a problem that was made up (*implying there is a chance that the problem is not even answerable in the first place*)

Comment: @J. Dionisio: It's easy to make up combinatorial problems for which an exact symbolic answer is not likely to be achievable. If the problem was from a book or competition, the reader would expect the problem to have a known answer, so might be willing to spend a fair amount of time on it. In the future, please provide such context. In this case, the context is "a problem my cousin made up". That's fine, but we should at least be advised of it.

Comment: The problem of finding the closed form solution for this is *incredibly* tedious, probably requiring the use of inclusion-exclusion principle over no fewer than 52 events, possibly even requiring as many as $52\cdot 15$ events...  I would not attempt this and would settle for an approximation, an experimental simulation, or if I'm really bored and willing to wait a very long time a computer brute force (*keeping in mind that $52!$ is a very large number and it would require a large amount of memory and time to do such a brute force calculation*)

Comment: @quasi I see, I didn't know this was the case, was hoping for a nice solution. Appreciate all the atention :)

Comment: @J, Moravitz: I agree with all your comments, but as regards a brute-force exact count, note that $52! \approx 8{\times}10^{67}$, so the large amount of memory exceeds the number of atoms in the universe! And even if that amount of memory could be magically be obtained, you would have to wait a very long time for the result!

Comment: @quasi there are ways to make the count smaller using symmetry, e.g. assume WLOG that ace of spades is top card and assume all spades occur in ascending order, dropping it down by ten orders of magnitude to $\binom{51}{12}\cdot 39!\approx 3\cdot 10^{57}$.  There may be additional simplifications that can be made to further drop the count, but not far enough to make it viable that I can see.

Comment: Correcting my previous comment, memory is not the issue; it's time. You only need to store one deck, which is modified in place so as to loop through the potential permutations, and as you loop, you keep count of the number of qualifying shuffles. But $3{\times}10^{57}$ iterations is out of computational range (for today's computers).

Comment: @JMoravitz: As Darth Vader might say: you underestimate the power of computers :-) See my answer below. (I did need my entire $16$ GB of memory, though.)

Comment: The [ENUMERATION OF CARLITZ MULTIPERMUTATIONS](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.04177.pdf) is a simpler problem than this one, and it doesn't have a simple solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a complete enumeration and thus an exact value for the probability, we can classify ranks according to which suits are left in them. There are $2^4$ different suit patterns for the $13$ ranks, onto which they can be distributed in $\binom{16+13-1}{16-1}=\binom{28}{15}=37442160$ different ways. We also have to remember which card was last played, for which there are at most $52$ possibilities, so we have at most $52\cdot37442160=1946992320\approx2\cdot10^9$ different states to process. We can do this stepping through the $52$ cards one at a time and tallying the number of admissible ways there are to reach the possible states.

[Here's Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/a5026a3854a1740f992ace8e3b0342e2) that does this. The result is that

$$
1609436968954808435644946271743718475717055824496860279603200
$$

different deals out of the total of

$$
52!=80658175170943878571660636856403766975289505440883277824000000000000
$$

are admissible, which yields a probability

\begin{eqnarray*}
&\frac{1609436968954808435644946271743718475717055824496860279603200
}{80658175170943878571660636856403766975289505440883277824000000000000}\\\\&=\frac{5258385993865270320943168907713343815039252427}{263528070245000096386506036857149662453104640000000000}\\\\&\approx1.9954\cdot10^{-8}
\end{eqnarray*}

in good agreement with Ross' estimate and quasi's simulation.

Note that I didn't make use of the permutational symmetry among the suits. That would require a bit more programming effort, but would further substantially reduce the number of states that need to be processed.

Comment: I like the approach (+1). I'll try to verify your results when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly speaking each card after the first has a $\frac {15}{51}$ chance of causing a failure, or a $\frac {36}{51}$ chance of success.  This ignores correlations between the cards, but should not be far wrong.  To succeed $51$ times in a row, the chances would be $$\left ( \frac {36}{51}\right)^{51} \approx 1.9\cdot 10^{-8}$$

Comment: I probably didn't express myself well, but I'm looking for an exact solution

Comment: I suspect an exact solution is very hard.  I think this is convincing that it is very rare.

Comment: Your heuristic estimate seems fine to me (+1). I would guess that an exact symbolic solution is not achievable, even with computer assistance.

Comment: @nbegginer $36!/51!$ has nothing to do with the problem.  The result of $(\frac{36}{\color{red}{52}})^{51}$ (*note the denominator change*) would be correct for dealing $52$ cards from an infinite shoe (*i.e. dealing with replacement*), but accounting for replacement in this problem does *not* simply mean "turn the numerator and denominator into factorials."  The correct expression, as discussed elsewhere in this thread, is going to be far too messy and is still expected to result in a final answer around $10^{-8}$, certainly not in the range of $10^{-24}$.

Comment: Using a simulation with $10^{\,10}$ randomly shuffled decks, exactly $195$ of them satisfied the specified restrictions. Hence, noting that
$$\frac{195}{10^{\,10}}=1.95{\times}10^{-8}$$
the simulation provides empirical support for Ross Millikan's heuristic estimate.

Comment: @quasi: With a standard deviation of about $\sqrt{195}$, that's in good agreement with the exact result.